# why is setting observable in knockout.js not working

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to explicitly set a default value on some observables, but after setting them and checking their values they return undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Interestingly the selectedCustomerType is set as expected, however the other 2 variables, selectedPlatform and selectedPricing are null. What is my silly mistake?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <script src='static/javascript/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
  <script src='static/javascript/knockout-3.0.0.js'></script>
  <script src='static/javascript/merchant.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <span id='customer_types' data-bind='foreach: availableCustomerTypes()'>
      <input data-bind='value: value, checked: $root.selectedCustomerType'>
      <span data-bind='text: label'></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select id='merchant_platforms'
            data-bind='options: availablePlatforms(),
                       optionsText: "label",
                       optionsValue: "value",
                       value: selectedPlatform'>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select id='merchant_pricings'
            data-bind='options: availablePricings(),
                       optionsText: "label",
                       optionsValue: "value",
                       value: selectedPricing'>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var MerchantModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.merchant = ko.observable();

  self.availableCustomerTypes = ko.observableArray([]);
  //    {'label': 'Red', 'value': 'R'},
  //    {'label': 'Blue', 'value': 'B'}
  //]);
  self.availablePlatforms = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.availablePricings = ko.observableArray([]);

  // was originally setting default values here, but this gets blown away after
  // ko.applyBindings() gets called in the $(document).ready() function below
  self.selectedCustomerType = ko.observable();
  self.selectedPlatform = ko.observable();
  self.selectedPricing = ko.observable();

  // load data
  self.load = function() {
    self.setDefaults();

    // load UI lookup lists asynchronously, etc...
  };

  self.setDefaults = function() {
    self.selectedCustomerType('R');   
    self.selectedPlatform('Tango');
    self.selectedPricing('Credit Plus');

    // calling self.selectedCustomerType() returns 'A' as expected
    // calling self.selectedPlatform() returns undefined?? Why?
    // calling self.selectedPricing() returns undefined?? Why?    
  };
}

// activate knockout.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var merchantModel = new MerchantModel();
  ko.applyBindings(merchantModel);

  // load initial data via ajax (in this case just UI lookup lists, etc...)
  merchantModel.load();
});
```

Comment: The issue is because because the option binding has chosen to *reject* the supplied value and thus updates the observable with undefined: i.e. there is no "Tango" entry in the `availablePlatforms` observable.

Comment: Thanks. This is really the 'first' correct answer, but it's a comment so I can vote for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropdowns are empty. Value is set to something.

That is invalid and value will be adjusted automatically because it is not in the dropdown list. First item from dropdown list is being assigned to provided value variable. First item is undefined therefore your value becomes undefined.

Comment: Ah thanks! I didn't realize knockout was actually doing 'validation' as well. I guess I need to my asynchronous lookup lists to load before trying to set alternative defaults (ie: not the first item in the list).